# Show Name field no work

Tags: 2013

I am adding modified by column in list definition but only account name is displayed, how display a name not account in my list ?

```
 <Field ID="{03324DBA-CT5C-2tr3-BWSS-1DIEKAERF£5D}" FieldRef="Editor" 
             RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="User" List="UserInfo" Name="Editor" 
             SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"         
             DisplayName="$Resources:core,Modified_By;" 
             StaticName="Editor" FromBaseType="TRUE" Required="FALSE" Group="" ShowField="Name" 
             AuthoringInfo="$Resources:core,name;" TextOnly="TRUE" AllowHyperlink="TRUE" />
```

How to show name not account in list ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `ShowField="Name"` to `ShowField="Title"` to show user display name.